# css: how to force images to scale at same amount?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images with two s that has no margin between each row.

But when i resize the browser window the images start to scale (that's not a bad thing) and start to get a margin between the images in the second row.

Is there a way to force the images to scale without margin?

My HTML:

```
        <ul class="staff-photos">
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/kevin_willy.jpg", alt: "Kevin Willy", title: "Kevin Willy") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/marc_willy.jpg", alt: "Marc Willy", title: "Marc Willy") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/markus_gygax.jpg", alt: "Markus Gygax", title: "Markus Gygax") %>
          </li>
          <li class="first-row-last">
            <%= image_tag("footer/sabine_gygax.jpg", alt: "Sabine Gygax", title: "Sabine Gygax", class: "first-row-last") %>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="staff-photos">
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/edith_hansmann.jpg", alt: "Edith Hansmann", title: "Edith Hansmann") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/christine_jean.jpg", alt: "Christine Jean", title: "Christine Jean") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/angela_widmer.jpg", alt: "Angela Widmer", title: "Angela Widmer") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/andrea_schneider.jpg", alt: "Andrea Schneider", title: "Andrea Schneider") %>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= image_tag("footer/vreni_uhlmann.jpg", alt: "Vreni Uhlmann", title: "Vreni Uhlmann") %>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
ul.staff-photos {
    li {
      display: table-cell;
      float: none;
      max-width: 225px;
      max-height: 281px;
    }
    li.first-row-last {
      max-width: 450px;
      max-height: 188px;
    }
    img {
      filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      opacity: .8;
    }
    img.first-row-last {
      height: 281px;
    }
    img:hover {
      filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide a working example with rendered html and css, this code is unable to modify by us, and this means will be hard to debug and identify the problem. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can use the images as backgrounds and set them to cover. Maybe that can solve the gap problem :)

Comment: because of the use of title attribute and mouse hover css background-image is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete " display: table-cell;" from your css

```
ul.staff-photos 
{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
}


ul.staff-photos li 
{
   flex:1 0 225px;
}
```

http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: i had to do some more adjustements but your display flex hint pointed me to the right direction, thanks!